# chrome.runtime.getManifest() is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to work with some javascript that accesses chrome.runtime in Google Chrome.  The script calls the chrome.runtime.getManifest() function, but my console says that function is not defined.  I've read through Google's documentation on this subject, and it should be there.  I've done some research, and for everyone else, using this function seems to be a non-issue, so I feel like I'm missing something.  However, when I run console.log(chrome.runtime); I see this:

[image: Console]

It appears that only two functions are defined in this object, connect and sendMessage.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.  These functions are only available when the javascript is running from a Chrome App.

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome extensions, this method is only available in the background scope.