# unit testing for chrome api using jasmine

Tags: google-chrome-app, karma-jasmine

How can I test chrome.runtime.getManifest() using jasmine? Below is what i tried:

```
 var manifestData = {"name": "Pearson App Chromebook Edition", "version": "0.0.1", "manifest_version": 2};
  beforeEach(function() {
    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('chrome.runtime', {
        getManifest: function () {
          return manifestData;
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

I am getting 'TypeError: chrome.runtime.getManifest is not a function' error. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help you- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230357/chrome-runtime-getmanifest-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was:

```
chrome = {
      runtime: {
        getManifest: function(){}
      }
    };
    spyOn(chrome.runtime, 'getManifest').and.returnValue(manifestData);
```

where manifestData is the mock of manifest.json