# ReferenceError: browser is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am running this piece of code and the firefox is giving error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined

```
const manifest = browser.runtime.getManifest();
```

So far I've tried using this:

> var browser = browser || chrome;

Still in this, firefox is throwing a new error that is
`Chrome is not defined`

Comment: "I am running this piece of code" — Precisely *how* are you running that code? (i.e. what are you typing it into and how are you trying to get Firefox to execute it?)

Comment: To be precise, I am running this by Live Server provided by Visual Studio Code.

Comment: That doesn't sound like anything even vaguely related to writing an extension. Try following Mozilla's instructions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension#Trying_it_out

Comment: That is because I'm not making an extension. I am making a speech to text converter for Firefox. There is no specific Converter for Firefox and Safari. This is me implementing for Firefox.

Comment: If you aren't making an extension, why did you include the [tag:firefox-addon] tag?!  … and try to use the `browser` API which is only available to extensions!

Answer (score 19):

The respective browser references are only defined in their respective scopes.

You might want to do something like this to remain platform independent.

```
if (typeof browser === "undefined") {
    var browser = chrome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is only accessible when the js is running from a Chrome app. Meaning this is only available from background scope.

And the firefox does not have any browser or chrome property since ver 65.

Please have a look on these:

source stackoverflow answer: [chrome.runtime.getManifest() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230357/chrome-runtime-getmanifest-is-not-defined)

Chrome doc: [chrome.runtime](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest)

Firefox removal info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/getManifest

Hope these will help.

Comment: Actually, that helped but not completely. In Firefox, there is an addon extension named Firefox-Voice that is depreciated. That addon uses the same thing inside its code and it is running. I am trying to replicate that. That extension is about to be removed. But that thing is not running locally on my system. I'm using a Live server from VSCode to run the same code for reference but the code is throwing error every time we use 'browser' .

Comment: Unfortunately, that link for the Firefox Removal info is now broken.

Comment: I ave a similar issue, can you have a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71559792/error-browser-is-not-defined-while-testing-firefox-temporarily-add-on?noredirect=1#comment126476255_71559792