# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 I have this exception but I don´t know what is this

Tags: json, syntax-error, unexpected-token

some errors on Chrome after run my jsp, I don't know what happens:

```
adblock-onpage-icon-cs.js:172 Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at onScriptLoad (adblock-onpage-icon-cs.js:172)
    at adblock-onpage-icon-cs.js:183globalstorage:1 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at handleRequest (globalstorage:47)
```

This is the code in js but, the but I can't understand the mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("json");
$.ajax({
    //connect to a Servlet
  url: "ServletReportes",
type:"POST",
dataType:"json",

  success: function( result ) {
  console.log(result);
}
}); 
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: browser is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330672/referenceerror-browser-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone else, the first error has nothing to do with your code. This error shows sometimes when you have the **adblock** extension installed on your browser.

It is often fixed just by **uninstalling and installing again the extension**, otherwise you can dismiss the error as should not affect your code.

The second error also does not seem an error in your code but in the response, probably the response of the ajax call not being a valid JSON format.